# PHP: Adding echo contents inside an other

Tags: php, tags, echo, phpthumb

I am using one php echo to add a meta tag og:image as follows:

**1**

```
echo "<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"https://example.com/Gallery/$b/$new/imagename-$b-$new-$three.jpg\" />";
```

and echos this image url: https://example.com/Gallery/book/new/imagename-book-new-3.jpg

**2**

And I started using phpThumb to resize the image dimensions in the url parameters (as I didnt find an easiter way), and the echo is:

```
echo '<img src="'.htmlspecialchars(phpThumbURL('src=https://example.com/Gallery/book/new/imagename-book-new-3.jpg&w=100&h=200', '/phpThumb/phpThumb.php')).'">';
```

What I need to do is merge the 2 echo (without `img src` part) inside the first!

I tried a lot, and what I want is something like:

**Result**

```
echo "<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"'.htmlspecialchars(phpThumbURL('src=https://example.com/Gallery/$b/$new/imagename-$b-$new-$three.jpg&w=100&h=200&iar=1', '/zJ/phpThumb/phpThumb.php')).'\" />";
```

Comment: Why doesn't your last snippet work as desired?  Ah, change single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: It is PHP. Maybe preg_replace_callback, I am new to this and couldn't try it.  If possible edit it as you see right and post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change single quotes to double quotes so that the middle concatenated portion is executed (not printed as a static string).

```
echo "<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\""
     . htmlspecialchars(phpThumbURL("src=https://example.com/Gallery/$b/$new/imagename-$b-$new-$three.jpg&w=100&h=200&iar=1", '/zJ/phpThumb/phpThumb.php'))
     . "\" />";
```

Comment: Still not working, it gives an error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()" and doesn't load the page.

Comment: Whoops, need to change the quotes on the first parameter of `phpThumbURL()` too because it contains variables.